# using "keep" or "discard" from purrr to filter lists based on two conditions

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to use `keep` or `discard` from the `purrr` package to filter some list by two conditions. That is, with the data below I would like to filter the `p.value` when it is `< 0.060` and `> 0.050`.

Applying the following obviously doesn't work `keep(d, ~.x$p.value > 0.05 & ~.x$p.value < 0.10)`.

Data:

```
d <- list(ABMD = structure(list(statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -2.88823930907752), 
    parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), alternative = "stationary", 
    p.value = 0.222153876057991, method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", 
    data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"), ATVI = structure(list(
    statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -2.86560166108736), parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), 
    alternative = "stationary", p.value = 0.231115731952747, 
    method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"), 
    ADBE = structure(list(statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -2.91292875187715), 
        parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), alternative = "stationary", 
        p.value = 0.212379749850693, method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", 
        data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"), AMD = structure(list(
        statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -3.46654255102478), parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), 
        alternative = "stationary", p.value = 0.0592779965240372, 
        method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"), 
    AKAM = structure(list(statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -3.67846516682619), 
        parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), alternative = "stationary", 
        p.value = 0.0380202892654308, method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", 
        data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"), ALXN = structure(list(
        statistic = c(`Dickey-Fuller` = -2.93110833009175), parameter = c(`Lag order` = 3), 
        alternative = "stationary", p.value = 0.205182767184581, 
        method = "Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test", data.name = "Cl(.)"), class = "htest"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need the double `~`.  It is anonymous function.

```
keep(d, ~.x$p.value > 0.05 & .x$p.value < 0.10)
```

It would be similar to `Filter` expression in `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) x$p.value > 0.05 & x$p.value < 0.10, d)
```

In the OP's code, it is doing double `function`

```
Filter(function(x) x$p.value > 0.05 & function(x) x$p.value < 0.10, d)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the `~` could only be applied to one function at a time. I was looking for a `keep2` type function!

Comment: @user113156 here, it is just a single anonymous function.  You can create any number of expressions out of that single function call